# Filter object by array and view by this array Viewjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

It's a json feed has one array with object and object with objects: I am try to filter an object which is in array by another array like:

```
members = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Ruta"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Paul"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Raymond"
    }
]

roles = {
    0: {
        id:  1,
        title: "admin",    
        member: [1,2],
        status: 
    },
    1: {
        id:  2,
        title: "editor",    
        member: [1]
    },
    2: {
        id:  3,
        title: "moderator",    
        member: [3]
    }
}
```

**I try to get roles by member like this, but it doesn't work**

```
members() {
    return Object.values(members).filter((el) => { 
        return this.roles.map((id) => { return id }).includes(el) 
    })
},
```

get in Vue

```
<div v-for="(member) in members">
    <div>
        {{member.name}}
    </div>
    <div v-for="(role) in roles">
        {{role.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**I would like to get a result:**

```
Result: 

    Ruta
       - admin
       - editor
    Paul
       - admin
    Raymond
       - moderator
```

Comment: are you getting some error? or just not getting the result?

Comment: I would suggest you to change structure so member has roles instead of role having members.

Comment: Also you have invalid JSON with `status:`

Answer (score 0):

First `members` is an array so `Object.values(members)` will peobably return an error.

Second I think the logic should be the other way around, first you need to map over members and then for each member you add the filtered roles.

```js
  members() {
    return members.map(member => {
        return {
          ...member,
          roles: Object.values(roles).filter(role => role.member.includes(member.id))
        }; 
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const members = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Ruta"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Paul"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Raymond"
  }
];

const roles = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "admin",
    member: [1, 2],
    status: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "editor",
    member: [1]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "moderator",
    member: [3]
  }
];

const output = members.map(x => ({
  name: x.name,
  role: roles.filter(xx => xx.member.includes(x.id)).map(x=>x.title)
}));

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(output)));
```